# what is the port 33060 for mysql server ports in addition to the port 3306

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2019

background purpose: I want to restrict inbound connection to MYSQL server only for specific host by setting inbound rules of windows firewall.

MYSQL server port is open on 3306.

However, when I open firewall setting, I can see two ports are opened on 3306 and 33060 as follows:

[image]

what is that? Should I restrict 33060 as well?

Comment: Certainly, why not, but you're probably not using it anyway. Check with `netstat`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne what is the part?

Comment: What is what part? What are you talking about now?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne sorry. I wanted to ask, what is the port? the port 33060.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The port for X Protocol (**mysqlx_port**), supported by clients such as *MySQL Shell, MySQL Connectors* and *MySQL Router*, is calculated by multiplying the port used for classic MySQL protocol by 10. For example if the classic MySQL protocol port is the default value of **3306** then the X Protocol port is **33060**.

See MySQL Port Reference Tables for more information.

The MySQL X service, is listening on all interfaces, by default over localhost, on TCP port 33060 and clients can connect to it through x protocol. So you need to restrict it for specific host to ban it to connect through x protocol. I suggest use it just for localhost.

You can see open ports by mysql through the following command:

> sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 3306

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the OP's question "Should I restrict 33060 as well?" I understand, question looks a bit labe, but though... Is there any suggestion for an average user?

Comment: To disable listening on that port, you can add this to your server's .cnf file under the `[mysqld]` section: `mysqlx=off`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.3.0
UnableToConnectException: Unsupported protocol version: 11. Likely connecting to an X Protocol port.

You are trying to connect port 33060, whereas you should connect using 3306.