# WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata, Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Im trying to insert some simple data in my local mysql database and i have a problem.
Connecting succeeded in mySql workbanch.
I tried to change the dialect. It didn't work.

stacktrace with WARN and error:

```
sie 08, 2021 7:03:38 PM org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker hibernateProviderNamesContain
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] will be used instead.
sie 08, 2021 7:03:38 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: myDatabase]
sie 08, 2021 7:03:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/mojabaza]
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=tutorial}
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
...
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
sie 08, 2021 7:03:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unsupported protocol version: 11. Likely connecting to an X Protocol port.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
...
```

it's my persistance configuration
I tried to change the dialect and user. It didn't work.
:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myDatabase"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="tutorial" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Password1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/mojabaza" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I wrote a simple main class to test the connection

```
package info.yakubus.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDatabase");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        
        
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

and pom with dependency configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.yakubus</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Port number 33060 seems a little high.

Comment: The most interesting message of your log is `ERROR: Unsupported protocol version: 11. Likely connecting to an X Protocol port.` Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63559166/3736575). Seems like that you have configured the wrong port number.